# Interaction with browser elements in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to automate the web browser application wherein I am not clear about the best approach:
I want to do a click of an image button . Amon these which one should i go for:

1.By finding the element and then doing a click

2.By exceuting a javascript using the JavaScriptExecutor

3.Corresponding to the image buttons click there are **key** events. e.g When I press the key b on my keyboard, the back image button also gets pressed.

Experts please advice which is the best way to handle this.
Also for the keys can I automate it. Already the keys are defined it also includes **right** and **left arrow.Will this work**.Are all key events supported?

Please help.

Comment: Can you please a bit more specific. Do you want to just click on the image or perform some other operation after clicking on the image?

Comment: I will be doing some actions like on click of the image button the control will move up and down on the menu list in the same page.

Comment: Not sure if I understood. You mean to say when you click on a button the page will move up or down is it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's easy, if want to click on the button, then just click to it like

```
new FirefoxDriver().findElement(By.id("image-button")).click();
```

1. Use JavaScript only as a last resort (there some corner cases in testing so the elements are for example not achievable with Selenium API).
2. Use keys only if you test keys. So do this as a separate test. You can press any key you want through [Actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

Very Easy solution.

WebElement imgBtn = (new FirefoDriver()).findElement(By.id("its_own_id"));

imgBtn.click();